# Python List of tuple how to remove duplicates?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a small doubt I have a list of tuple

```py
test_lst=[[],
 [],
 [('boy', 20, 23), ('boy', 30, 33)],
 [],
 [('school', 20, 25), ('school', 30, 35)],
 [('jack', 20, 24), ('Mile', 40, 44)]]
```

I do not want duplicates my final list should look like

```py
final_lst=[[],
 [],
 [('boy', 20, 23)],
 [],
 [('school', 20, 25)],
 [('jack', 20, 24), ('Mile', 40, 44)]]
```

How can I do that in an optimized way?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Does no duplicates include other lists, or is it just within each list?

Comment: @BeRT2me it does not include other lists

Comment: @erip I was trying through set but it did not work for me.

``` 
non_dup_list = [list(set(x)) for x in test_lst]``` 

It did not work for me since I had span info in the tuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `itertools.groupby` to check for duplicates of first value in tuple

```
import itertools
test_lst=[[],
 [],
 [('boy', 20, 23), ('boy', 30, 33)],
 [],
 [('school', 20, 25), ('school', 30, 35)],
 [('jack', 20, 24), ('Mile', 40, 44)]]
final_lst = [[next(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(x, lambda y: y[0])] for x in test_lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final_lst = []
for lst in test_lst:
    names = []
    inner_lst = []
    for x in lst:
            inner_lst.append(x) if x[0] not in names else None
            names.append(x[0])
    final_lst.append(inner_lst)

print(final_lst)
```

Output:

```
[[], [], [('boy', 20, 23)], [], [('school', 20, 25)], [('jack', 20, 24), ('Mile', 40, 44)]]
```